# Parse Query For Objects Created Within last 5 Minutes

Tags: android, parse-platform

I need to filter objects saved in parse by the ones that have been created within the last 5 minutes. How exactly can i use the `createdAt` date column to filter this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", new Date(new Date().getTime() - 5 * 60 * 1000));
```